# Accelerometer sampling rate jitter with 'onSensorChanged'

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sampling

I am using a samsung galaxy ace3 to sample accelerations. `getMinDelay()` gives me 10 000 µs. When I log my accelerations with that period to a csv file, I get delays around the correct period with a random jitter which is sometimes huge (above 0.5 second).

Does someone know how to improve this?

Here are the delays between samples that I got.

[image: Delays vs time]
[image: Delays vs time (Zoom)]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {    
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private int cpt = 0;
private boolean start;
private List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

}


public final File dir = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/test/");
public FileOutputStream afos = null;
public OutputStream stream = null;

public void startButton(View view) {
    start = true;
    cpt = 0;
    mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, mSensor, 10000); // 10000 µs -> 10 ms
    openCsvFiles(dir, "data.csv");
    stream = new BufferedOutputStream(afos);
}

public void stopButton(View view) {

    for (String record: records) {
        try {
            stream.write(record.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    try {
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        afos.close();
        start = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float ax, ay, az;
    String axs, ays, azs, ts, line;
    if (start) {
        cpt++;

        ax = event.values[0];
        ay = event.values[1];
        az = event.values[2];

        ts = String.valueOf(event.timestamp);

        long ns = android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();

        line = ns+", "+ cpt+", "+ ts + "," + ax + "," + ay + "," + az + "\n";

        records.add(line);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, mSensor, 10000);
```

Instead of hard coded value 10000 use **SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST**

```
mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Comment: It doesn't get better. Furthermore, I would like to sample at fixed rate and not necessarily 100Hz.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for onSensorChanged says that you should not do much processing within the method because it blocks further samples coming in. It says that on this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Here, you are creating a string from the data and adding it to an ArrayList. It takes a certain amount of time to create the string, and usually that will be added quickly into the ArrayList, but there are occasions when the ArrayList will need to grow to accommodate the next object and on such occasions it takes a long time because it needs to allocate a new (larger) array internally and copy the references from the old array to the new one.

Consider adding the SensorEvent to a FIFO such as an ArrayDeque within the method and then processing these in another thread. It should improve the jitter.

I don't think the Android system provides any guarantees that the jitter will never be large, but this should help.